# tighter bound on the sum of sub-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A = [A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n]$ is a matrix, and each $A_i$ is a column-wise sub-matrix of $A$. Given a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, a bound of $\| \sum_{i=1}^n A_i v_i \|_2$ (spectral norm) in terms of $\|A\|_2$ (spectral norm) and $\|v\|_2$ (Euclidean norm) is desired. A naive approach is
\begin{align*}
\| \sum_{i=1}^n A_i v_i \|_2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|A_i v_i \|_2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|A_i \|_2 |v_i| \leq \|A\|_2 \|v\|_1 \leq n\|A\|_2 \|v\|_2.
\end{align*}
However, this may be too loose. Can I get rid of $n$ on R.H.S.? That`s to say,
\begin{align}
\| \sum_{i=1}^n A_i v_i \|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|v\|_2, (1)
\end{align}
Eqn. (1) is trivially true when each $A_i$ is a column of $A$. Then is this also true when each $A_i$ is a column-wise sub-matrix with arbitrary number of columns? By numerical experiments using random trails, it seems the answer is positive.